# How do I get Calibre to fetch news?

Tags: ebooks, calibre

After spending a while figuring out Calibre's news fetching feature, and spending another while slowly editing the recipes as it maxed out the cpu, I was disappointed to find that resulting the ebooks were all 0.0Mb. I disabled my proxy but still no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ebook-convert ~/.config/calibre/custom_recipes/(your recipe) test.epub --test -v -v` in a terminal and see if any error or warning messages are produced.

Comment: I don;t have a custom_recipes folder even though I have edited several of the stock recipes. Trying a stock recipe I get the same problem . I see that the program is still using the proxy I  normally use, 127.0.0.1:8123 even though I have disabled it with gnome.

Comment: I logged out after disabling the proxy and it works now. Curious how it wouldn't obey the gnome proxy applet.

Comment: Most likely it only reads the proxy once, since it can't hook into `gconf` (or whatever it is this week) properly. BTW, the builtin recipes can be run the same way but they live somewhere else; I'd have to check where though (my primary calibre environment is on OSX).

Comment: Yes, but I restarted Calibre after updating the proxy settings. I searched for calibre recipes and there aren't any in my home folder.

Comment: The system ones won't be in your home folder. Again, I would have to dig to find out where they are on Ubuntu, but it will be under `/usr` somewhere for an Ubuntu package and under `/opt/calibre` for the standard install. As to the proxy, the other possibility is that it uses the environment, which indeed will require logout/login if your window/desktop manager isn't smart enough to update its own environment when the proxy settings are changed.